# How do I access a field inside array inside object inside array in the aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I had this data structure as my document:

```
{
  id: 1,
  customers: [
    {
      id: 2,
      addresses: [
        {
          phone: "555-342",
          zipCode: "1946873193",
          addressLine: "whatever"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I access the `phone` property in the aggregation framework?
`$ROOT.customers.0.addresses.0.phone` doesn't work as a field path expression.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt

Comment: @AlexBlex yes I saw that but can't understand how to use chained "arrayElemAt"s for the cause

Comment: The syntax is `{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$customers", 0 ] }`, not `customers.0`. Applies to all arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to handle two nesting levels but then you can add $project to get `phone` property.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  $addFields: {
    selectedElement: {
        $let: {
           vars: {
              fstCustomer: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$customers', 0 ] }                
           },
           in: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$$fstCustomer.addresses', 0 ] }
        }
     }
  } 
},
{
  $project: {
    phone: "$selectedElement.phone"
  }
}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the `$arrayElemAt` in following way.

Outer `$let` expression to get the first customer and inner `$let` expression to get the first address element of first customer followed by projection of phone property.

```
db.col.aggregate(
{"$project":{
  "phone":{
    "$let":{
      "vars":{
        "customer":{"$arrayElemAt":["$customers",0]}
      },
      "in":{
        "$let":{
          "vars":{
            "address":{"$arrayElemAt":["$$customer.addresses",0]}
          },
          "in":"$$address.phone"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}})
```

Comment: I see ```$let``` was the missing key. @mickl user answered a min sooner so I should accept his despite the similarity in answer